# How to make turtles gradually grow in size as they age?

Tags: variables, netlogo, agent

I am working on an ecosystem model that consists of fish, sharks, and plankton. The fish eat the plankton for energy and the sharks eat the fish. However, I need the sharks and fish to grow in size as they age. However when I use the code below, the sharks and fish don't gradually increase; they start off small but after a few ticks they immediately grow into their largest maximum size.

I have tried the following code but as I explained, the fish and sharks aren't growing in size gradually, but immediately after a few seconds.

```
to sharkGrow
  ask sharks
  [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse age < 12
    [
      set size size + 0.01 ; Growth rate
    ]
    [
      set size 12 ; Maximum size limit
    ]
  ]
end

to fishGrow
  ask fishes
  [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse age < 10
    [
      set size size + 0.1
    ]
    [
      set size 6
    ]
  ]
end
```

I have these two subprocedures that are called in the main procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine both fish and sharks grow in size. I think the only problem is, that you just don't see the difference (except if you have a bug somewhere else in your code). The increase in size is just minor compared to the final size.

Assuming you are starting with an age of 0 and a size of 1, your sharks will grow from size 1 (for age = 0) to size 1.11 (age = 11) and then suddenly increase up to a size of 12 (for age = 12). The same is true for the fish but less significant.

To test, you can right-click on one of your sharks/fish and inspect it (or use `inspect one-of sharks` in the Command Center). You will find the size in the properties of the inspect window. Start your simulation with low speed and see how the size increases.

So to solve your problem you need to adjust the increase in size. If you want to have a gradual increase, I would recommend scaling it to your final size (increase = final_size / final_age).

So for your code this could look like:

```
to sharkGrow
  ask sharks
  [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse age < 12
    [
      set size size + 12 / 12 ; Growth rate
    ]
    [
      set size 12 ; Maximum size limit
    ]
  ]
end

to fishGrow
  ask fishes
  [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse age < 10
    [
      set size size + 6 / 10
    ]
    [
      set size 6
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that your growth pattern (starting at size 1) is

1.01, 1.02, 1.03 ... 1.10, 1.11, 12.0 (!!!)
The jump from 1.11 to 12.0 is due to the fact that 1+12*0.01 isn't 12

If you call this method every tick, the sharks will reach their maximum size in 12 ticks, which is usually quite fast.
If you want the sharks to keep growing gradually, you need to drastically increase the value of your `if` statement.

something like

```
to sharkGrow
  ask sharks
  [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse age < 110
    [
      set size size + 0.1 ; Growth rate
    ]
    [
      set size 12 ; Maximum size limit
    ]
  ]
end
```

will grow smoothly from size 1 to size 1+110*0.1=12.